# defining numeric_limits max function for template class

Tags: c++, template-classes, numeric-limits

I have problem with defining function max for template class. In this class we kept a numbers not as simple integers, but as vector of numbers in some numeral system. And with defining numeric_limits i need to return representation of maximal number founded on a defined number system.

And i get many errors, when i'm trying to return class with maximal representation, but it works when returns integer.

**My template class:**

```
template<int n,typename b_type=unsigned int,typename l_type=unsigned long long,long_type base=bases(DEC)>
class NSizeN
{
  public:
    int a_size = 0; 
    vector <b_type> place_number_vector; // number stored in the vector

    NSizeN(int a){ //constructor
        do {
            place_number_vector.push_back(a % base);
            a /= base;
            a_size ++;
        } while(a != 0);
    }

    void output(ostream& out, NSizeN& y)
    {
        for(int i=a_size - 1;i >= 0;i--)
        {
            cout << (l_type)place_number_vector[i] << ":";
        }
    }

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream& out, NSizeN& y)
    {
        y.output(out, y);
        return out << endl;
    }
}
```

**At the end of .h file i have this :**

```
namespace std{
template<int n,typename b_type,typename l_type,long_type base>
class numeric_limits < NSizeN< n, b_type, l_type, base> >{

public :
     static NSizeN< n, b_type, l_type, base> max(){

        NSizeN< n, b_type, l_type, base> c(base -1); 
        return c;
     }
}
```

I've tried this with const, with constexpr, and it doesn't work. I've no idea how to get rid of this errors :

```
error: cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
 std::cout << std::numeric_limits<NSizeN<3> >::max() << endl;
error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = NSizeN<3>]'
 operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
```

And this is what i'm trying do in main:

```
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<NSizeN<3> >::max() << endl;
```

This is my assignment so don't judge the way of doing this, because it's my teacher choice and I hope I presented my problem fairly comprehensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you are facing is that you try to bind a temporary returned by your `max()` function to a non-const reference for the output operator.

The cleanest solution would be to declare the output operator as:

```
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream& out, const NSizeN& y)
```

and your `output` function as

```
void output(ostream& out) const
```

Note, that I also removed the unused second parameter for the `output` function. The const reference can be bound to both l-values and r-values, so it will work for the temporary returned by the `max()` function as well.

**Edit**
As @n.m. pointed out, you also don't use the stream that is actually passed to the `operator <<` and just use the `std::cout`. The proper way to implement it is to simply use the stream (in your case just replace the `cout << ...` with `out << ...` in your `output` function. This will let statements such as `std::cerr << std::numeric_limits<NSizeN<3> >::max();` work as intended.

Comment: If you look closely, the first parameter to `output` if also unused.